# Hide touch keyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard, windows-phone-7.1

Is it possible to not show system keyboard, when you tap textbox? Ive created custom keyboard and can work with textblock only, because of this i cant delete just parts of sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `IsReadOnly` to `true` then the user can still select the text in a `TextBox` to copy paste and the OS doesn't show the software input keyboard when selected. You can still alter the contents of the `TextBox` through code though. Eg;

```
<TextBox x:Name="ExampleTextBox"
         IsReadOnly="True"
         Text="Initial Content" 
         GotFocus="ExampleTextBox_GotFocus"
         />
```

And in your code behind;

```
private void ExampleTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) {
  ExampleTextBox.Text += " ... focused!";
}
```

Would prevent the user from entering text via the software keyboard but will append "... focused" everytime they give focus to the `TextBox`. Contrived example, but you get the idea.

The only other thing I'd suggest is to re-style the `TextBox`. By default when `IsReadOnly` is set the `TextBox` will provide visual cues that it can't be modified by the user. Which isn't the case here.

Comment: Wow, easy one! Thank you. Just the thing i wanted. Now i can use custom keyboard and get things from textbox like selected text&copy! Will check it later and accept. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. You can use this same trick (with appropriate styling) to make what appears to be a `TextBlock` but that the user can copy the contents of.

Answer (score 1):

if the user touches the keyboard, the keyboard will get focus.

the only option you as a developer have is to catch it and call this.focus moving focus away from textbox.

This will however mean that there will be a flicker where default keyboard pops up and is hidden.

I know this because i have a keyboard app. There is no other way.

Comment: But without focus textbox behaves just like textblock then..For example there will be no possibility to select parts of text

Comment: why do you want to write an app if you can't figure out the first hurdle ? Text box has a text property. All operations can be done without putting focus on it.

Comment: There are many keyboard apps.. some even has source available online http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx have a look at this link